# iOS AWS Cognito Authentication with Multiple Devices

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

We are working on an iOS Application that has been using Unauthenticated Access to Cognito. We are now adding an Identity Provider: Cognito User Pools.

We are seeing that when Device A does the login process, from Unauthenticated to Authenticated, the Cognito ID stays the same (as expected). Then when Device B logins in, Unauthenticated to Authenticated. We would expect the user to get the Authenticated Cognito ID from Device A, this is not the case.

Even so, perhaps they all transitioned to Cognito ID from Device A? That also doesn't seem to be the case. Both devices have separate Cognito ID's but are using the same user account from a Cognito User Pools. But neither share a Cognito ID, which seems to go against what the documentation describes.

Can someone confirm what we are doing is a valid workflow, and perhaps what we might be doing wrong?

We are storing the Cognito ID in a back end server to tie that data to a user, but with the Cognito ID's changing unexpectedly, its hard to come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the AWS Cognito identityId will be the same for an authenticated user even if he is authenticated on two different devices.

What you describe is not the expected behavior.

Probably you are not "really" authenticated.  What does "really" authenticated mean?  It means that you have gone through the process of wiping the keychain and getting credentials, because it is the credentials provider that goes to the identity provider and gets the login dictionary (and then assigns an appropriate identityId (that's when it gets to be the same as the other device)).

You can tell if you are "really" authenticated by looking in the AWS Console for Federated Identities, and looking at the identity browser.  The "logins" count on the identity in question should NOT BE 0... it should show (in your case) 1 and if you click on the identity, you should see that it is authenticated with your pool.

The fix?  After you come back from logging in and getting a session you must "Get Credentials for ID"  (which in the ios sdk is the "credentials" method).

This link may help [cognito notes and diagram](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/master/cognito%20diagram.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we are still hitting a roadblock with our implementation, we even cloned your project example on your github to compare, and the implementations are very close.

Comment: Our main problem that we see during our login is that getSession isnt returning the tokens. userPoolUser (AWSCognitoIdentityUser) .isLoggedIn is false all the way though, inside the getSession continue block, and inside the credentials method. It seems we need to login the user in. Even supplying a bad password to getSession allows the completion block to call as if it was no different than a successful user/password.

Comment: If using interactiveAuthenticationDelegate the didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError delegate method is called for both success and failure.  The optional param "error" is nil for the success case.  ... or maybe you are just doing getSession with uid and password. Regardless you need to make sure the credentials provider is properly hooked up to the pool and that is done when creating the credentials provider with AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider... specifying the pool_id AND your userpool (pool) as the identityProviderManager.  That way the pool.logins gets called.

Comment: credentials() -> task.result has the tokens, but the count inside the federated identities page is still zero and isLoggedIn still reports false? Any ideas?

Comment: Also, the tokens are entirely managed by the sdk.  You should see them in the logging of the AWS RESTful interface, if you have logs turned on, but you don't have to do anything with tokens directly.

Comment: We are trying to do the former of the two: "There are two ways to sign in: explicitly or when credentials are needed via a delegate." - explicitly, which should just be by getSession() as we understand it.

Comment: ok, so that makes me suspect that your user pool is not properly connected to your credentials provider.  Because  when you call "credentials" that calls identityProviderManager's logins function and that function returns a proper login dictionary (via an AWSTask).  You can see your dictionary by calling pool.logins().continuewith.... and looking at the result, but if you are not seeing the logins logged in the log then the credentials provider is not seeing them.  If you have a logins dictionary, you are logged in. But you will only get credentials for it if credentialsProvider knows about it

Comment: It bears mentioning that your cognitoUserPool needs to be configured on the console as an authentication provider for the identity pool.

Comment: We will take a look at our credentials provider and user pool code. We do appreciate your help so far, its been wonderful.