# Cannot Sync Amazon Cognito Datasets Across Multiple iOS Devices

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-cognito

I have been able to sign up, confirm, and sync a users dataset across a single iOS device, but am running in to issues when trying to sync on other devices. I am struggling to figure out why this is happening. During the sign up process I synchronize the dataset and I can see it in the federated identities identity browser. But when syncing on other devices I am not able to read from my dataset. Is the user information stored locally on the device? Is my Cognito sync logic incorrect? Is there another way I should be approaching this? Below is my code for syncing the user data on login. Thanks in advance.. I am really confused on how to resolve this issue.

```
func login(usernameText : String, passwordText : String){
    user = self.pool!.getUser(usernameText)
    var userString = ""
    print("Login Current thread \(Thread.current)")

    user?.getSession(usernameText, password: passwordText, validationData: nil).continue({ task in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(" Session Current thread \(Thread.current)")
        if let err = task.error {  // some sort of error

            print("LOGIN FAILED")
            print(err)
            self.userConfirmed = false
            //print(err.userInfo["message"] as! String)
        }
        else { //Successful login!

            // this gets our token from the User Pool
            let ret = task.result! as AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession
            let myToken = ret.idToken?.tokenString;

            let customcedentialProvider = AWSCustomIdentityProvider(tokens: [AWSCustomIdentityProvider.CognitoTokenKey : myToken!])
            let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE, identityPoolId: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,  identityProviderManager: customcedentialProvider)
            let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

            // wipe cached creds
            credentialsProvider.clearKeychain()
            credentialsProvider.clearCredentials()

            // hit it
            credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continue({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Current thread \(Thread.current)")
                if (task.error != nil) {
                    print("Error: ")

                } else {
                    print(credentialsProvider.identityId!)
                    // the task result will contain the identity id
                    let credentialsProviderUser = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.usEast1,identityPoolId:credentialsProvider.identityId!)

                    let configurationUser = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.usEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProviderUser)
                    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configurationUser

                    // Initialize the Cognito Sync client
                    let syncClient = AWSCognito.default()
                    // Get User Dataset
                    let dataset = syncClient?.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset")
                    print(dataset?.size() as Any)
                    let userData = dataset?.getAll()

                    for (key,value) in userData!{ if "\(value)".characters.count > 0 {userString.append("| Key: \(key) Value: \(value) ");print("| Key: \(key) Value: \(value) ")}
                    }

                }
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

                defaults.setValue(userString, forKey: defaultsKeys.keyOne)
                defaults.setValue(passwordText, forKey: defaultsKeys.keyTwo)

                defaults.synchronize()

                }
                return nil
                })
            }}
        return nil
        })
}

// Class for custom tokens
class AWSCustomIdentityProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager
{
    static let FacebookTokenKey = "graph.facebook.com"
    static let GoogleTokenKey = "accounts.google.com"
    static let TwitterTokenKey = "api.twitter.com"
    static let CognitoTokenKey = "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX"

    var tokens: NSDictionary = [String : String]() as NSDictionary

    init(tokens: [String : String]) {
        self.tokens = tokens as NSDictionary
    }

    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> { // AWSIdentityProviderManager delegate method
        return AWSTask(result: tokens)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not really getting authenticated (logins count is 0) and that the sync'ing you see occuring is associated with unauthenticated identities.

I suspect this is because you are missing a call to credentials.  It is not enough to get the identity id, if you never call credentials then... the credentials provider never calls you logins(), if he never calls logins() then he never sees a login has been done, and thus he never increments the logins count (which is why you might see 0 logins in the identityBrowser on the identity).  That means you are using an unauthenticated identity.

If you have a 0 logins count, you are not authenticated.

This answer may also be helpful to you.

[multiple devices cognito ios login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853535/ios-aws-cognito-authentication-with-multiple-devices)

It is unclear from your question how you are generating the tokens for google and twitter etc, but I should point out that the user pool is capable of returning logins.